# Is there any way to apply strict typing to the parameters of a function?

Tags: php, oop, types

I know some of the beauty of PHP comes from loose typing, but I want to make a PHP class with strictly-typed, object-oriented functions.

I tried what I thought would work:

```
... [index.php]

24: include './documentation-builder.php';
25: $builder = new DocBuilder('Documentation');

... [documentation-builder.php]

5:  class DocBuilder
6:  {
7:      function __construct(string $title)
8:      {
9:          $this->title = $title;
10:     }
11: }
```

But I got the following error:

> **Catchable fatal error**: Argument 1 passed to DocBuilder::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in \path\to\index.php on line 25 and defined in **\path\to\documentation-builder.php** on line **5**

The fact that is says "Argument 1 ... must be an instance of string, string given" makes me think I am close, but forgot to set a flag somewhere.

**How do I require strict typing on my PHP functions?**

Comment: "_must be an instance of string, string given_" means it must be an object of the class 'string' but you passed an actual string.  Type hints are for arrays and objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only type hinting for classes and arrays are supported at this time.

> Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string. Resources and Traits are not allowed either.

[source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

Comment: is there any way to pass a String in an OO way then?

Comment: @Supuhstar unfortunately not that I'm aware of. [This article](http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/06/Scalar-type-hinting-is-harder-than-you-think.html) may provide some more insight.